# Can't send/receive OSC messages to/from other processes

Tags: process

I made my first attempt at OSC with (Doom) Emacs.  I got the example in [osc.el](https://delysid.org/emacs/osc.html) working, but I couldn't make it either send or receive messages to/from other processes, even if they are running in Emacs itself (I tried SuperCollider both with Emacs and SCide).  I can send OSC with SuperCollider in Emacs to a Python OSC server running in a terminal, but not to the elisp script, or from the elisp script to the Python server.

Here's my code:

```
(require 'osc)
(setq tkt-osc-client (osc-make-client "localhost" 7770))
(setq tkt-osc-server (osc-make-server
                      "localhost" 7770
                      (lambda (path &rest args)
                         (message "Unhandled: %s %S" path args))))

(osc-server-set-handler tkt-osc-server "/tkt" (lambda (path &rest args) (message "Received: %s %S" path args)))

(osc-send-message tkt-osc-client "/tkt" 1.5 1.0 5 "alo")

;; (delete-process tkt-osc-client)

(provide 'tkt-osc)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,

EDIT:
I managed to send messages to another process with:

```
(require 'osc)
(setq tkt-osc-client nil)
(setq tkt-osc-server nil)

(setq tkt-osc-server (osc-make-server
                      "localhost" 7770
                      (lambda (path &rest args)
                        (message "Unhandled: %s %S" path args))))

(osc-server-set-handler tkt-osc-server "/tkt" (lambda (path &rest args) (message "Received: %s %S" path args)))

(defun tkt-make-client (host port)
  (make-network-process
   :name "OSC client"
   :host host
   :service port
   :type 'datagram
   :family 'ipv4))

(defun tkt-osc-connect (host port)
  "Connect to a remote HOST with PORT."
  (if tkt-osc-server (delete-process tkt-osc-server))
  (if tkt-osc-client (delete-process tkt-osc-client))
  (setq tkt-osc-client (tkt-make-client host port)))

(defun tkt-osc-close ()
  (delete-process tkt-osc-client)
  (delete-process tkt-osc-server))

(provide 'tkt-osc)
```

But the server part still doesn't receive anything, not even the messages sent from this script's client, which was working before...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the default `osc-make-server` function.  By adding the property `:familiy 'ipv4` to the `(make-network-process)` function it seems to work.

Here's the full working code:

```
(require 'osc)
(setq tkt-osc-client nil)
(setq tkt-osc-server nil)

(defun tkt-make-osc-server (port default-handler)
  "Listen to OSC messages on PORT."
  (make-network-process
   :name "OSCserver"
   :coding 'binary
   :filter #'osc-filter
   :host "localhost"
   :service port
   :server t
   :type 'datagram
   :family 'ipv4 // <--------------------------- this makes it work
   :plist (list :generic default-handler)))


(defun tkt-make-osc-client (host port)
  (make-network-process
   :name "OSC client"
   :host host
   :service port
   :type 'datagram
   :family 'ipv4))

(defun tkt-osc-connect (host port)
  "Connect to a remote HOST with PORT."
  (if tkt-osc-server (delete-process tkt-osc-server))
  (if tkt-osc-client (delete-process tkt-osc-client))
  (setq tkt-osc-client (tkt-make-osc-client host port))
  (setq tkt-osc-server (tkt-make-osc-server 7770
                                            (lambda (path &rest args)
                                              (message "Unhandled: %s %S" path args)))))

(defun tkt-osc-close ()
  (delete-process tkt-osc-client)
  (delete-process tkt-osc-server))

(provide 'tkt-osc)
```